# Ubuntu Chrome: How to read a cookie from a python script

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies, ubuntu

I am creating a little application that has two parts: One of them is displayed inside a Chrome browser and the other is a local application programmed in Python.

In Chrome, the user has a `<select>` to choose his/her preferred language. That information is stored by Chrome in a cookie.

I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve that language preference (meaning, reading the cookie) so when I run the local application, it will be displayed on the same language the user already selected with Chrome.

I can not change the system's locale, though (which is what would probably make the most sense). That has to remain in English, but if the user selects *Chinese* as preferred language through Chrome, and then launches the local application, I would like that application to be able to start in *Chinese*.

I've been looking at the [command line switches](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html) for Chrome, but I haven't seen anything too helpful. At most, the `--enable-file-cookies` option, and then try to open and parse the cookie file... somehow, but all the information I've been able to find is pretty vague.

Thank you in advance!

Update. Further searching ([1](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-opening-google-chrome-files-history.html), [2](http://www.techknowme.com/2010/10/how-to-read-the-google-chrome-cookies-file-on-a-mac/)) seems to indicate that Chrome stores the cookies using SQL lite. I am looking into this. Maybe there's hope with that...

Comment: are both the python client and the website talking to a server? if so, you could simply store the language preference there (sent by the browser) and retrieve the info from the python client...

Comment: @Hoff -> I thought about that too. The python client is not exactly talking to the server, but the server is running in localhost so (for practical purposes) the answer is "yeah". I could have the server storing the language preferences. I'll keep it as a last resource... It's also that I'm curious about the cookie management in Chrome and well... If I already have the preferred language stored in the hard drive (in the cookie) by Chrome, and I can avoid re-storing it using the server, that'd be great. Thanks for the idea, though *:)*

Comment: The command sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies seems promising... Will keep posting :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, as I mentioned in the comments to my question, sqlite3 sounded promising... The day I learn to read, I'll conquer the world!!

Anyway, just in case is helpful for someone else:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sqlite3
import pwd

_cookieName = "preferredLanguage"

def getPreferredLanguageFromCookieDB():
    retval="en-US"
    cookieDBFilename = os.path.join(pwd.getpwuid(1000).pw_dir, ".config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies")
    if os.path.isfile(cookieDBFilename):
        connection = sqlite3.connect(cookieDBFilename)
        querier = connection.cursor()
        numCookiesMatching = int(querier.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cookies WHERE (host_key="127.0.0.1" or host_key="localhost") and name="%s"' % (_cookieName)).fetchone()[0])
        if numCookiesMatching == 1:
            retval = querier.execute('SELECT value FROM cookies WHERE (`cookies`.`host_key`="127.0.0.1" or `cookies`.`host_key`="localhost") and `cookies`.`name` = "%s"' % (_cookieName)).fetchone()[0]
        elif numCookiesMatching == 0:
            print("::getPreferredLanguageFromCookieDB > No cookie for '%s' found. Assuming wizard hasn't run yet, which is weird, but not critical" % (_cookieName))
            retval="en-US"
        else:
            raise KeyError("Found %s cookies matching %s in file %s. This shouldn't have happened" % (numCookiesMatching, _cookieName, cookieDBFilename))
            retval=None
    else:
        print("::getPreferredLanguageFromCookieDB > Cookie 'db' (actually, file) %s doesn't exist" % (cookieDBFilename))
        retval="en-US"

    return retval


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Prefered language: %s" % getPreferredLanguageFromCookieDB()
```

This little snippet will connect to the Cookies "database" (is actually just file but, anyway...) and read the value of the "`preferredLanguage`" cookie issued by either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. It will crash if there's more than one "`preferredLanguage`" cookie issued by localhost.